# How to create custom condition and action in Sitecore Commerce 9

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am struggling with creating a custom promotion plugin and I am new with Sitecore XC. I would like to create custom condition/qualification and action which should work as expected. All I want is that my condition should appear on below dialog and work.

[image]

I have followed below articles to do so

https://horizontalintegration.blog/2018/10/09/sitecore-9-commerce-custom-promotion-condition/

https://www.konabos.com/blog/creating-a-custom-plugin-for-sitecore-commerce-xc-9-part-1/

I am receiving a common error as below while following the above articles. It seems it could be one of the reason. And, my commerce engine stops responding due to this error. could be one of the culprits.

[image].

It would be really grateful if anyone can help me to resolve this and ready to do screen sharing discussion if required.

Comment: Make sure that you are referencing a correct version of Microsoft.OData.Edm dll

Comment: Which one is the recommended version to use? Currently, I am using 7.5.3

Comment: It depends on XC update version. Which version are you using?

Comment: Sitecore XC 9 update 2

Comment: Microsoft.OData.Core and Microsoft.OData.Edm should be 6.15.0.0

Comment: I have changed to 6.15.0.0 but still facing same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial (https://horizontalintegration.blog/2018/10/09/sitecore-9-commerce-custom-promotion-condition/), a crucial step is missing. Your assembly has to be registered in the ConfigureSitecore.cs of your plugin to the rules engine before it is visible in the dropdown:

```
services.Sitecore().Rules(rules => rules.Registry(reg => reg.RegisterThisAssembly()));
```